# Parse - Check for new Object

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I am using parse.com for a little project. How can I check whether a new object has been uploaded to a column? I searched for, but I didn't found anything witch helped.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a key on your `PFUser` class called `dateCheck` for example.
2. Save/set the current date for `dateCheck` when the current user leaves the application (goes to background, logs out etc..).
3. Use `[PFUser currentUser][@"dateCheck"]` to query the objects that were uploaded after your current user leaved the app.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a way to check whether an object has been saved at all, you can check for `createdAt==nil`.